# win32gui multiscreen gives strange coordinates

Tags: python, win32gui

Anyone know how win32gui windowRec coordinates behave on multiscreens,
The documentation does not say much:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windef/ns-windef-rect

```
import json, win32gui
from typing import List, Optional

def getWindows() -> Optional[List]:
    """ get all windows on desktop """
    windowlist = []
    def callback(hwnd, wl):
        if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
            dat = {}
            dat['windowText'] = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
            dat['x'], dat['y'], dat['x2'], dat['y2'] = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
            if dat['windowText'] == '':
                return None
            wl.append(dat)

print(json.dumps(getWindows(), indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

config: screen0|screen1|screen2

I run in a window on screen1, below is fullscreen on screen0:

```
  {
    "windowText": "xxxxx Mozilla Firefox",
    "x": -32000,
    "x2": -31871,
    "y": -32000,
    "y2": -31972
  },
```

I move the run window screen0 and run, same window untouched:

```
  {
    "windowText": "xxxx Mozilla Firefox",
    "x": -8,
    "x2": 2056,
    "y": -8,
    "y2": 1160
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives you a REFERENCE based on your Primary Monitor.   So if you have 3 monitors and your center one is the primary, the left one would have negative X coords. So that is the reasoning.  In some software such as ImageGrab etc, the 0,0 point isnt the TOP LEFT of the Primary ( Center Monitor ) but instead the 0,0 is Global Space, TOP LEFT of the left most monitor.

Comment: Thanks, This should be in the documentation. I also tested pyautogui, but `moveTo(0,0)` only move to the upper left corner of the current monitor. I will test out ImageGrab.

Comment: One of the things I was noticing was local scope vs global scope, so I had to convert my Points to a global reference for say using pyautogui to do things effectively across other monitors.

Comment: Literally last night, for example i finally got something working because screen caps were not working outside of my main monitor, and needed to figure out why.   Spent about 10 hours debugging and understanding why it was returning just a black image.